# I try to collect coordinate from text to gridview but My Data Gridview is empty

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

[image: gridview with empty data (screenshot)]

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Dim filePath As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Dim lineNumber As Integer = -1
        Dim searchString As String = "TABLE: ""JOINT COORDINATES"""

        ' Check if file exists
        If Not File.Exists(filePath) Then
            MessageBox.Show("File not found")
            Return
        End If

        ' Read the file content
        Dim fileContent As String = File.ReadAllText(filePath)

        ' Open the file for reading
        Using fileStream As New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            Using streamReader As New StreamReader(fileStream)
                Dim data() As String = fileContent.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

                ' Loop through each line in the file
                Dim line As String
                Do
                    lineNumber += 1
                    line = streamReader.ReadLine()
                    If line IsNot Nothing AndAlso line.Contains(searchString) Then
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop Until line Is Nothing

                ' Parse the data and add to DataGridView
                Dim dataGrid As New DataGridView()
                With dataGrid
                    .ColumnCount = 2
                    .Columns(0).Name = "Joint"
                    .Columns(1).Name = "Coordinate"

                    Dim startIndex As Integer = lineNumber + 1
                    While startIndex < data.Length AndAlso data(startIndex).Contains("Joint=")
                        ' Parse the data
                        Dim jointStr As String = data(startIndex).Substring(data(startIndex).IndexOf("Joint=") + 6, data(startIndex).IndexOf(" ") - (data(startIndex).IndexOf("Joint=") + 6))
                        Dim x As Integer = Integer.Parse(data(startIndex).Substring(data(startIndex).IndexOf("XorR=") + 5, data(startIndex).IndexOf("Y=") - (data(startIndex).IndexOf("XorR=") + 5)).Trim())
                        Dim y As Integer = Integer.Parse(data(startIndex).Substring(data(startIndex).IndexOf("Y=") + 2, data(startIndex).IndexOf("Z=") - (data(startIndex).IndexOf("Y=") + 2)).Trim())
                        Dim z As Integer = Integer.Parse(data(startIndex).Substring(data(startIndex).IndexOf("Z=") + 2, 3).Trim())

                        ' Add the data to DataGridView
                        Dim jointCoordStr As String = "(" & x & "," & y & "," & z & ")"
                        .Rows.Add(jointStr, jointCoordStr)

                        startIndex += 1
                    End While
                End With

                ' Show the DataGridView
                Dim form As New Form()
                With form
                    .Controls.Add(dataGrid)
                    .ShowDialog()
                End With
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

here is my text I try to get coordinate
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QVHVDyI1CyytpwcBDRRcJcFXZm-6pceG/view?usp=share_link](https://stackoverflow.com)

I expect to show to my gridview like this

joint     coordinate
1         0,1,0
2         0,1,10.93
3         0,11,0
.
.
.

[image: Expected output of gridview (screenshot)]

Comment: Please read the description of a tag before applying it to your question. The VS tag explicitly states that it is for IDE questions and not for questions about code simply written in VS.

Comment: Please provide an example of your data directly, not as a file we need to download. If you don't know how to format properly in a question, you can spend some time in the Help Center to learn.

Comment: What is the actual problem here? You've got data and you've got code. EXACTLY where and how does the behaviour of the code not meet your expectations? You need to have debugged it thoroughly and be able to identify exactly what it's doing that you don't expect or not doing that you do expect. If the code behaves exactly as expected and you still don't get the expected result then it's your expectations that are the issue.

Comment: I also have to wonder why you are creating a `DataGridView` in code when you could just add it to the form in the designer. If you don't want it to be visible then just set the `Visible` property to `False` and then show it in code.

Comment: I would suggest that you use a `TextFieldParser` to read the data. Instead of reading all the data first and then looping through it to populate the grid, read the data line by line and add a row for the current line.

Comment: There's also little point calling `File.ReadAllText` and then `String.Split` when you could call `File.ReadAllLines`.